# window.location.href not working in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, url, google-chrome-extension

`this.window.location.href` is not working in chrome extension
in the html file i tried this function in the script:

```
function myFunction()
{
   var pl = this.window.location.href;
   var sWords= localStorage.getItem(pl);
   document.write(pl);
}
```

and it gives me:

```
chrome-extension://ebeadbfnnghmakkbimckpdmocjffkbjc/popup.html
```

so what i should do to get the link of the page?

Comment: @RobW Link removed .. thanks for the pointer .. sorry ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the currently selected tab via [`chrome.tabs.query`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-query) method. You need to pass two options:

1. `currentWindow : true`
2. `active : true`

It will return an array of tabs that match the criteria. You can get the URL from there. Like this:

```
chrome.tabs.query(
    {
        currentWindow: true,    // currently focused window
        active: true            // selected tab
    },
    function (foundTabs) {
        if (foundTabs.length > 0) {
            var url = foundTabs[0].url; // <--- this is what you are looking for
        } else {
            // there's no window or no selected tab
        }
    }
);
```